# Will i obtain same tuple from GiveElement() in all enviroments?

Tags: c#, .net

```
int counter = 0;
int[] array = new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };

(int, int) GiveElement() => (array[++counter], array[counter]);
```

Using
[dotnetfiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/jvCmeU) (.Net7)
compiler i received (2,2). ChatGPT yields (2,1).

So , I'm wondering if order of returned values will be the same for all compilers and always counter will be incremented for first element and same element will be returned as second?

Is it not something like "unspecified behaviour" in C++?

Comment: _"ChatGPT yields (2,1)."_ - ChatGPT is text generation tool (and now images AFAIK), why do you take it in account?

Comment: You must remember that ChatGPT is a moron that just regurgitates people's answers regardless of whether they are correct, without any understanding whatsoever.

Comment: This is not unspecified behaviour in C# by the way - it's very precisely defined. From [the specification](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/expressions#12623-run-time-evaluation-of-argument-lists): `During the run-time processing of a function member invocation (§12.6.6), the expressions or variable references of an argument list are evaluated in order, from left to right`

Comment: So first `array[++counter]` is evaluated, which itself will increment `counter` first before indexing the array. Then `array[counter]` is evaluated, which will use the previously-incremented value of `counter`.

Comment: Thank you @MatthewWatson, please add an answer, so i can accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [@Matthew Watson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/106159/matthew-watson) mentioned in comment:
From the [specification](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/expressions#12623-run-time-evaluation-of-argument-lists):

> During the run-time processing of a function member invocation (§12.6.6), the expressions or variable references of an argument list are evaluated in order, from left to right